# When do we omit "the" when using it with next?

Tags: articles, definite-article

[Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/next)

I could not figure out why not use **the** with:

> Are you working **(the)** next week?
>
> We’re going to plant some new flowers **(in the)** next spring.
>
> Ollie’s coming to stay the week after **(the)** next.
>
> You are **(the)** next.

Though it has been used in:

> I don’t know how I’m going to manage from one day to **the next**.
>
> I’ll finish the work in **the next** few days. You can pay me then.
>
> **The next** person she met was an old lady who had lived in the village all her life.

Please explain the rule.

Comment: How come you're asking a question and adding a link to the resource where the answer is  at the same time?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh There is unfortunately no single "rule" regarding when we can, should, or must omit the article in English. There are [many questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles?sort=votes) on the subject and many answers! A useful article is [here](http://www.englishgrammartutor.com/articles.htm), too.

Answer (score 1):

Words such as *tomorrow*, *today*, names of days or months such as *March* or *Tuesday*, full dates such as *January 3rd* don't use articles.

> I'm working today.

*Next week* or *next* with one of the above falls in the same category.

---

*Next* can be an adjective, as well as a noun.

Adjectives can follow forms of *to be*, so saying something like *You are next* is fine, and no *the* is needed.  Nouns can also follow forms of *to be*, so saying *You are the next* is also OK.

Comment: Please explain **Adjectives can follow forms of to be, so saying something like *You are next* is fine, and no the is needed. Nouns can also follow forms of to be, so saying *You are the next* is also OK.**