# How to treat the names of Months? Do we need any articles?

Tags: articles

How to treat the names of Months? Do we need any articles?

1 March last year was warmer than March this year.

2 Last year's March was warmer than this year's March.

3 The March of last year was warmer than the March of this year.

4 The March of last year's was warmer than the March of this year's.

Comment: 4 should be 'The March of last **year** was warmer than the March of this **year**'. 2 is fine. 1 and 3 are equally acceptable. You should not have capitalised 'Month' in the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for articles when it comes to months. There is also no need to use articles before the names of days, months, seasons and holidays.

E.g.

> I'm working today.

But **no need** does not mean you cannot use articles. You *can* use articles like in the example you gave

> The March of last year was warmer than the March of this year

Read another [ELL post on using articles but for "next"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97758/when-do-we-omit-the-when-using-it-with-next)